# Ansible cloud stack module nested loop for security groups and ports

Tags: ansible, automation, configuration-management, ansible-playbook, cloudstack

I'm trying to set multiple security groups at once using the ansible cloud stack module. The yaml file currently looks like this:

```
- name: add inbound tcp rules to security group web
  cs_securitygroup_rule:
  security_group: web
  start_port: "{{ item }}"
  end_port: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - 80
    - 443
```

The problem is there could be a vast number of security groups. So this code block would repeat over and over again, which seems not like a good solution. So I'd like to turn this whole thing into one single loop and pass the arguments using dictionaries. The datastructure cloud look something like this:

```
cs_security_groups:
  web:
    - 80
    - 443
  monitor:
    - 9090
    - 9100
    - 9333
  default:
    - 22
```

I simply can't get this to work using any kind of loop because a security group could have an arbitrary number of ports. Am I missing something or is this approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solved the issue.

```
- name: add inbound port(s) to the security groups
  cs_securitygroup_rule:
    security_group: "{{ item.0.key }}"
    port: "{{ item.1 }}"
  loop: "{{ cs_security_groups | dict2items | subelements('value') }}"
```

This works, but there may be a better solution. :-)